# How to create a migration to remove an index only if it exists, rather than throwing an exception if it doesn't?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, rails-migrations

Right now, the current migration might fail, if the `books` table doesn't have `created_at` or `updated_at` fields:

```
class AddTimestampIndexes < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def up
    remove_index :books, :created_at
    remove_index :books, :updated_at

    add_index  :books, :created_at
    add_index  :books, :updated_at
  end

  def down
    remove_index :books, :created_at
    remove_index :books, :updated_at
  end
end
```

Does `remove_index` take any options to silently proceed if it fails to remove the index rather than raising an error?

Answer (score 91, accepted):

You can use the `index_exists?` method within your migration to test whether the index you need to remove is actually there.

Take a look at the documentation here:
http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/ConnectionAdapters/SchemaStatements/index_exists%3F

I've not tested it, but you should be able to use something like this:

```
class AddTimestampIndexes < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def up
    remove_index :books, :created_at if index_exists?(:books, :created_at)
    remove_index :books, :updated_at if index_exists?(:books, :updated_at)

    add_index  :books, :created_at
    add_index  :books, :updated_at
  end

  def down
    remove_index :books, :created_at
    remove_index :books, :updated_at
  end
end
```

Although, by the looks of things, you really only want to create them if they don't exist?
This might be more appropriate for your migration:

```
class AddTimestampIndexes < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def up
    add_index  :books, :created_at unless index_exists?(:books, :created_at)
    add_index  :books, :updated_at unless index_exists?(:books, :updated_at)
  end

  def down
    remove_index :books, :created_at
    remove_index :books, :updated_at
  end
end
```

Answer (score 14):

#### Rails 6.1+ if_exists / if_not_exists options

Rails 6.1 added `if_exists` option to `remove_index` in order to not raise an error when the index is already removed.

Rails 6.1 added `if_not_exists` option to `add_index` in order to not raise an error when the index is already added.

As a result, your migration can be rewritten in the following way:

```rb
class AddTimestampIndexes < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def up
    remove_index :books, :created_at, if_exists: true
    remove_index :books, :updated_at, if_exists: true

    add_index :books, :created_at
    add_index :books, :updated_at
  end

  def down
    remove_index :books, :created_at, if_exists: true
    remove_index :books, :updated_at, if_exists: true
  end
end
```

Here is a list of the links to the corresponding PRs:

- [Add `if_exists` option to `remove_index`](https://github.com/rails/rails/pull/38967),
- [Fix index options for if_not_exists/if_exists](https://github.com/rails/rails/pull/39356).

Answer (score 9):

There is also `index_name_exists?(table_name, index_name)` method which let's you check for an index by it's name. It's helpful for checking for existence of multi-column indexes.

Documentation - [index_name_exists](https://api.rubyonrails.org/v5.2.2/classes/ActiveRecord/ConnectionAdapters/SchemaStatements.html#method-i-index_name_exists-3F)

Comment: Unfortunately that will only check if an index with the given name exists, whereas `index_exists?` will check for an index matching the given definition (correct columns etc)